# Выбор всех строк в функции

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, plsql

Добрый день!
Создаю функцию, суть в том, что в случае, если один из входных параметров = 1, то необходимо взять только одну строку (потом пойдет в цикл), если параметр не задан - то необходимо взять все строки)
Решил идти через decode, но не знаю, как обозначить в этом decode, что если параметр не равен 1, то "бери все".

Выглядит это пока так

```
where r.equipment_id = p_EquipmentId
  and rownum = decode(p_ForKR, 1, 1, X)
```

где Х обозначено место, куда нужно прописать это самое "бери все".
Если есть вариант более красивый и правильный - готов его применить, только наставьте.

Oracle 9i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем запросе можно вместо `X` взять `rownum`, тогда, если параметр `p_ForKR` не равен 1, у вас будет `rownum = rownum`.
Еще подобную конструкцию можно записать с помощью `nvl`, `coalesce` или `CASE`, но это в принципе другой способ записать то же самое (разве что `nvl` может вызвать небольшое проседание производительности на очень больших выборках).

Comment: Благодарю, то что нужно